# Is there a way with c# to access the currently playing song in Itunes?

Tags: c#, windows, itunes

I am super surpised I cannot find anything on this by googling. But I wish to access the currently playing song in Itunes using C# in windows.

Googling reveals something called COM which seems to be deprecated, or various info for using applescript or MAC OSX info.. I'm almost positing that Ventrilo accesses that information but it's been a while... so maybe they do not anymore... Surely there is an easy way to do this?

Any resources would be helpful. thanks.

Comment: COM is not depreciated as a technology and the "iTunes COM SDK" is the way to interface with iTunes on Windows.

Comment: thanks ended up finding it... just from the way it looked it wasn't being used anymore.. thanks!